# C# which data structure is suitable for efficient querying in both ways(forward and backward)

Tags: c#, data-structures

I'm considering how to decide data structures for this case.

In my application (kind of machine learning application), three classes exist `ImageData`, `LabelData`, and `ClassData`.
And list of `ImageData` and list of `ClassData` are needed, probably list of `LabelData` also.

Their relationships are shown in the figure at link(lack of reputation...).
[Images, Labels and Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy1LE.png)

- The program has a list of images
- The program has a list of classes
- Each image has multiple labels
- Every label indicates a class in the list of classes (by ref. type)

So I constructed data structure like this:

```
class ImageData {
    public List<LabelData> Labels {get; set;}
}
class LabelData {
    ClassData ClassData {get; set;}
}
```

If I count 'how many labels in a single image per class', it seems OK.
But If I count 'how many labels per class in all images' it seems little bit inefficient because a loop for images is needed. I know LINQ helps this issue, but I guess a more efficient way exists in the point of data structure.

Any comments are welcome, or pleases let me know any kewords to solve this issue.
Thanks!

==================== revised! ======================

It was not clear as other said, so I added more specific examples.

Conditions about this application:

- The program handles multiple images.
- User can draw a label to images.
- Multiple labels can be drawn to a single image.
- The program handles multiple classes, and a label must be assigned to one of these classes before it is drawn at the image.

Currently, I implemented classes like below

```
class ImageData {
    public List<LabelData> Labels {get; set;}
    public string ImagePath {get; set;}
    // constructor
    public ImageData(string imagePath) {
        Labels = new List<LabelData>();
        ImagePath = imagePath;
    }
}
class LabelData {
    public ClassData ClassData {get; set;}
    // constructor
    public LabelData(ClassData classData) {
        ClassData = classData
    }
}
class ClassData { }
```

and my application has data as:

```
private List<ImageData> _images;
private List<ClassData> _classes;
```

Here comes the issues. In my program I want to show some statistics, for example, number of labels.

First, if user want to know "number of labels in a single image(`_images[0]`) assigned as a single class(`_classes[0]`)":

```
_images[0].Labels.Count(v => v.ClassData == _classes[0])
```

It's not an issue for this first case, but secondly, if user want to know "number of labels in all images assigned as a single class(`_classes[0]`):

```
_images.Sum(v => v.Labels.Count(x => x.ClassData == _classes[0]))
```

But, I think this implementation of second case is not efficient because `_images.Sum(~)` implicates foreach loop of `_images`. If this program handles thousands of images, it gets slower.

So my question is that is there a better implementation of `ImageData`, `LabelData`, and `ClassData` to improve efficiency. For example, i) the program handles list of images, list of labels, list of classes; ii) and additionally handles other join index containers like `Tuple<int, int> LabelImageIndices`, `Tuple<int, int> LabelClassIndices`.

Which data structures fit this issue?
Or which keywords that I can find to solve this issue?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Is every label related to exactly one image?

Comment: `List` will be best for your requirement

Comment: @grek40 yes, a label shouldn't be shared to multiple images

Comment: @viveknuna could you explain more in detail?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking how to initialize a mutually recursive data structure? Regardless, don't assume that an simple implementation will be too slow before you try it.

Comment: @jinkyu *"a label shouldn't be shared to multiple images"* only answers half of my question... the other half: is every label associated to an image or can a label exist independently?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I think some data structures have efficient two way queries. In this case, query from images and query from classes. I want to know that specific data structures.
By the way thousands of images are handled in this application, so I need an efficient way :(

Comment: @grek40 label cannot exist independently.

Comment: There are multiple data structures that could serve such a purpose, but an example of how you plan to use the data would be needed to provide a decent answer. That said, I doubt that you really want what you think you want at this point. You probably want to transpose a specific list a images or labels, cache the result in variable, and iterate over it. In other words, you may well have an XY problem

Comment: @AluanHaddad I revised the question, please check below "===revised==="

Comment: As each image maintains a mutable collection of labels, you have to compute many labels match on demand. There are some minor optimizations you might make but their beneficial impact will be rather low and they would result in substantially more code. The reason this is difficult to optimize is that all of the collections, like `ImageData.Labels`, are mutable so you cannot precompute the results.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks for your comments! can you give me keywords about "minor optimizations" that you mentioned?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding about some functionality here... you mention, that *"`_images.Sum(~)` implicates foreach loop of `_images`"*, but it seems you don't realize that `.Count(~)` will also loop over your data. So, I suggest you give us some numbers... how bad is the performance impact that you want to mitigate? How many images / labels / classes are involved when the problem occurs?

Answer (score 0):

If it were a relational model you would have 3 entities exactly like your diagram.  Images, Classes and Labels. The only difference would be that the Labels would not be "owned" by any other entity but would exist in their own right with references to the List and Image.  You would need constraints to enforce some of your rules.

By doing this, you can run your query against any of the entities depending on your need.

In SQL you'd have indexes against Lable.PK, Label.ClassID, Lable.ImageID to help with performance.  In LINQ you'd need to pick better structures, such as IDictionary derivatives, though obviously a list could be made to work.

Comment: can you check the revised question? (below "=== revised ===")